# Problems with Robocopy

Tags: windows, command-line, robocopy

How shall I put this...

It's like: you can tell robocopy: "move the contents of this map to that map".

But you can't say: "move that map to that map, no matter the contents"(to be content of that map)

Or can you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a GUI for Robocopy that makes it much easier to use outside the command line called [RichCopy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.04.utilityspotlight.aspx?pr=blog).

Answer (score 1):

Robocopy by default should copy all contents, no matter what they are. If you mean recursively into all subdirectories, use `/E`:

```
robocopy C:\dir D:\backupdir /E
```

You can find a complete list of all available switches [here](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2007/05/07/robocopy-syntax-command-line-switches-and-examples/).

Answer (score 1):

I believe what the original poster was referring to was the fact that RoboCopy does not copy the root folder / source folder, but rather only its contents.

More information can be found here: [Robocopy does not copy the root folder and its time stamp](https://superuser.com/questions/379612/robocopy-does-not-copy-the-root-folder-and-its-time-stamp/383555)