# Robocopy does not copy the root folder and its time stamp

Tags: robocopy

Robocopy does not copy the root folder and its time stamp - it copies all subdirectories and files (when the appropriate options are set) and there seems to be no option/argument to tell Robocopy you want the root folder itself and its time stamp or attributes to be copied verbatim also.

So say I want I want to copy C:/Brushes

Robocopy will copy all its subdirectories and files into the destination, but not the Brushes folder itself, with all associated attributes and time stamp.

You understand what I am asking?  This is pretty basic and Robocopy seems to lack a option for it.  People have posed the question before in various forums but as far as I'm concerned, no one has answered the question.

[image]

Comment: This is a flyer, based on my experience with `rsync`, but what if you don't have a trailing slash at the end of your target folder? How about trying to modify the script at command-line level instead of using the GUI? I know for a fact that the command-line tool will do what you need.

Comment: @Randolph West: presently I don't have a trailing slash at the end of the target folder.  I still can't make Robocopy include the source folder and its attributes, etc. in the actual copy job.  Any ideas?

Comment: If there is no solution for robocopy, you could have a look at [xxcopy](http://www.xxcopy.com/) (there are freeware and commercial versions).

Comment: Yep, I understand completely and have added a working solution below. The real problem is that you have to specify all the files and folders in the root NOT to copy.

Answer (score 10):

```
robocopy %1 "C:\DestinationDirectory\%~n1" /E /V /DCOPY:T /LOG:"C:\DestinationDirectory\Copied.txt" /R:10 /W:30
```

Drop a folder onto the `bat` or use in *Send To*.
It will create folder with name & time stamp of source directory and copy all files.

Comment: thank you very much, was searching for that magic %~n1 operator

Comment: @hotzen, What does the `%~n1` do?

Comment: They are listed here: http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/percent.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: "Expands %1 to a file name."

Comment: Microsoft broke all their links, here has the percent tilde documentation for batch, https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Batch_Scripting#Percent_tilde

Comment: I think this answer boils down to *append the source folder name to the destination path* and use `/DCOPY:T` to copy the timestamp.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with the OP, not being able to copy the  root folder is a big shortcoming of robocopy. How about cheating and moving the brushes folder into a temporary folder, performing the robocopy operation on the temporary folder, then moving it back?

Something like:

```
md "c:\verytemporary" && move "c:\brushes" "C:\verytemporary"||( echo Line 1 error occurred & goto :eof )
robocopy c:\verytemporary d:\ /MIR /DCOPY:T
move "c:\verytemporary\brushes" "c:\" && rd /q "c:\verytemporary"||echo Line 3 error occurred
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `md D:\Backup\Brushes && robocopy C:\brushes D:\Backup\Brushes` from the command-line, substituting the correct paths.

Comment: Yeah, but you are creating a new folder which will not have the attributes of the original C:\brushes folder...?

Answer (score 2):

<sub>As I can see no good and easy solution in any of the answers :</sub>

If there is no solution for robocopy, you could have a look at [xxcopy](http://www.xxcopy.com/) (there are freeware and commercial versions).

There are of course many other alternatives to robocopy, some are listed [here](http://alternativeto.net/software/robocopy/).
See also [Best Free File Copy Utility](http://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-file-copy-utility.htm).

Comment: **`xxcopy`** is a great utility, but the freeware version has a prompt that you must respond to if you using any of a large list of command line switches. Using **`xxcopy`** from a command window, this extra prompt is irritating. But it prevents (complicates) use of **`xxcopy`** from a batch file at all.

Answer (score 1):

user105198's answer is the half way,

`D:\Backup\Brushes && robocopy C:\brushes D:\Backup\Brushes`  will indeed just create a new folder. You will need to append **/MIR** and /**DCOPY:T** to it

> With the **/mir** option, if the destination directory exists, the
>   destination directory security settings are overwritten. [*Technet*](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145%28WS.10%29.aspx)

```
/DCOPY:T :: COPY Directory Timestamps.
```

combined together, means : the source directory's attributes and timestamps will be mirrored to the created folder.

so:

```
D:\Backup\Brushes && robocopy C:\brushes D:\Backup\Brushes /MIR /DCOPY:T
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll find that Robocopy does exactly what you want, provided you tell it to copy folder timestamps (/DCOPY:T). From my experiments, I've found the following (seemingly undocumented) behavior to be true for Robocopy:

> All specified properties of the source directory are applied to the destination directory, regardless of whether the destination directory exists, doesn't exist, or has a different name from the source directory.

The specified properties can include (at least) the security information (/SEC) or folder timestamps (/DCOPY:T).

Therefore, in the following example, c:\destination\folder will be assigned the same timestamps as c:\source\folder.

```
robocopy c:\source\folder C:\destination\folder /E /DCOPY:T
```

I tested this with the versions of Robocopy included with Windows 7, Windows 8, and the Windows 2003 Resource Kit (/SEC parameter only). Note that only newer [versions of Robocopy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy#Versions) (XP026 and above) support the /DCOPY:T parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If you combine `/IF :: Include the following Files.` with `/E :: copy subdirectories, including Empty ones.` you get (close to) the desired effect:

```
C:\Temp\Robocopy Source Root>robocopy . "C:\Temp\Robocopy Destination" /E /IF "Brushes*"
```

Comment: What do you mean "close to"?  What is the limitation you are implying?

Comment: _Danger Will Robinson!!!_ Your suggestion seems to copy every folder in the current folder, not limit it to the folders beginning with "Brushes"

Answer (score 0):

Robocopy isn't really designed to do that easily. **However, there is a way.**

Root folder contains lets say 50 files and 40 folders. You only want folder X (but you also want it's time and date stamp).

```
ROBOCOPY c:\ d:\ /XF 50 root file names c:\boot.ini c:\bla.txt etc. /XD c:\windows c:\drivers c:\temp etc. /S /E /SEC /DCOPY:T
```

The /DCOPY:T tells it to keep the folder time stamps. The /XF specifies which files NOT to copy, /XD specifies which folders to NOT copy. Just don't specify folder c:\X.

The main drawback to this is researching all the folders and file names in the root and specifically calling them all here. If you are doing this a lot on different systems a script could be written.

**Working Example**

*robocopy c:\testing c:\abc /XF c:\testing\Testing.txt /XD "C:\testing\New Folder (2)" "C:\testing\New Folder (3)" /S /E /SEC /DCOPY:T*

**Root Working Example**

*robocopy c:\ d:\ /XF c:\Testing.txt /XD "C:\New Folder (2)" "C:\New Folder (3)" /S /E /SEC /DCOPY:T*

My test worked, I create a few folders and sub folders, c:\testing was root in this case, c:\abc was root of another drive (obviously they aren't really, but for this purpose it should make sense). The folder I wanted from the root was called "New Folder", as you can see I did not specify it in the /XD. Also, make sure you specify the c:\ or the names you use will be global. In other words if I didn't specify c:\testing in from of the Testing.txt file, it would omit it from ALL of the subfolders being copied. The /SEC will copy all the file security and time stamps.

Comment: Hmmm, I suppose you could use /XF c:\*.* to exclude all the root files. I'll test that when I'm in front of a machine and not on a phone.

Comment: Nope, c:\*.* is invalid, you'll have to manually list all of the files.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, using `/DCOPY:T` should solve all your problems.

But, I've seen this happen, and I'm not sure I'd call it a "bug", but rather a consequence of the sequence of operations (OK, bug).

This command should work to copy all files from `C:\Brushes` to `D:\NEWBrushes`, and `/DCOPY:T` should cause the timestamps of the source folder to be copied to the destination folder:

```
robocopy "C:\Brushes" "D:\NEWBrushes" /COPY:DAT /DCOPY:T
```

What I've seen (at least on some versions of Robocopy) is that the command succeeds, but the timestamp of the `D:\NEWBrushes` folder is set to the current date and time.

So it appears that the `/DCOPY:T` feature does not work for the "base" (topmost) folder you are copying.

I believe that it is working, but that the timestamp of the destination folder is being "stepped  on" by operations that are later in the operation sequence.

What I believe is happening for this command:

```
robocopy "C:\Brushes" "D:\NEWBrushes" /COPY:DAT /DCOPY:T
```

is something like this:

1. Create folder `D:\NEWBrushes` if it doesn't already exist
2. Copy the timestamp from `C:\Brushes` to `D:\NEWBrushes`
3. Copy files and sub folders from `C:\Brushes` to `D:\NEWBrushes`

It appears that Step 3, the modification of the contents of the folder `D:\NEWBrushes` causes the timestamp of `D:\NEWBrushes` to change.

For me, the "workaround" has been to run the `robocopy` command to copy the files and folders, then run the (same) `robocopy` command a second time.

So, the first time you run:

```
robocopy "C:\Brushes" "D:\NEWBrushes" /COPY:DAT /DCOPY:T
```

all the files and folders will be copied. Then running it again:

```
robocopy "C:\Brushes" "D:\NEWBrushes" /COPY:DAT /DCOPY:T
  (or)
robocopy "C:\Brushes" "D:\NEWBrushes" /DCOPY:T
```

The second time `robocopy` runs, no files or folders within `D:\NEWBrushes` will be modified, and the `/DCOPY:T` option will tell `robocopy` to copy the timestamp from `C:\Brushes` to `D:\NEWBrushes` (unless there are folders/files in `C:\Brushes` that have changed since the first run of `robocopy`).

Answer (score 0):

I was solving the root folders right now for one really quick and easy backup script with robocopy, there is an example. Should help to anyone:

```
$Destination="F:\Backup" #change destionation backup drive and foder
$BackupDirs="d:\folder1", "d:\folder2", "d:\folder3\subfolder", "d:\fodler4\subfolder\subsubfodler" #change source folders

#make a loop for every source folder
foreach ($Backup in $BackupDirs) {

#split folder name
$fdname = Split-Path $Backup -leaf

#define folder to create in destionation
$dirtocreate = Join-Path $Destination $fdname

#make directory, yes, some extra script to skip when exist should be in place, but -erroraction solved this in lazy mode :)
md $dirtocreate -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 

#copy with subfolders and log
robocopy $backup $dirtocreate  /s /nfl /ndl /log:c:\scripts\backup.log

}
```

Comment: So use this PowerScript and the problem is resolved, right?

Answer (score 0):

I have to copy more than 100 folders from one file server to another, In that case, I faced kind of the same problem.

I will share my experience with you, maybe this might help you -

Suppose,
(you want to copy `folderB` from Source to Destination ) -

you have  -  **\Source\folderA\folderB**

you want  -  **\Destination\folderB**

In that case, what I did is, first of all, I find out the lowest level directory name from the source path, Which is (folderB) is my case-

```
$source = "\\Source\folderA\folderB" 
$destination = "\\Destination\"
$FileName = Split-Path $source -Leaf    #output will be "folderB"
```

Now, I will use `robocopy` for copying the directory and all its subdirectories and files.

```
robocopy "$source" "$destination\$FileName" /DCOPY:T /e
```

***/DCOPY:T*** -  copy the timestamp of the directory

***/e*** - Copies subdirectories. This option automatically includes empty directories.